# Tengo problemas con mi Chat de PHP y SQL

Tags: php, sql

Estoy desarrollando un Chat pero estoy teniendo problemas para sacar los mensajes que he enviado yo como emisor y los mensajes que me han enviado a mi como receptor.

He creado 2 consultas SQL, una para sacar los mensajes que he enviado como emisor y la otra para sacar los mensajes que he enviado como receptor

```
<?php

 // Sacar los mensajes que he enviado yo | Emisor
 $stetament = $conexion->prepare(
    "SELECT users.id_user, users.name, users.surname, users.photo_profile, messege.messege, messege.photo_messege, messege.create_at_messege FROM messege INNER JOIN users ON users.id_user = messege.id_receptor WHERE users.id_user = $receptor"
);

$stetament->execute(array());
$emisor = $stetament->fetchAll();

 // Sacar todos los mensajes que recibo yo | Receptor
 $stetament = $conexion->prepare(
    "SELECT users.id_user, users.name, users.surname, users.photo_profile, messege.messege, messege.photo_messege, messege.create_at_messege FROM messege INNER JOIN users ON users.id_user = messege.id_emisor WHERE messege.id_emisor = $id"
);

$stetament->execute(array());
$receptor = $stetament->fetchAll();
```

**Aclaratoria de variables:**
La variable **$receptor**, contiene el id que estoy recibiendo por **$_GET['user']**, ósea, es el id de la persona a la que le quiero enviar el mensaje.

La variable **$id**, contiene el id del usuario que esta conectado actualmente, ósea es el id del usuario que ha emitido el mensaje. en mi caso mi id = 1 | int(1)

Pero mi cerebro no aguanta tanta informaciones y me tranco y no logro solucionar el problema.
Quiero que los mensajes que están marcado en **Rosado** aparezcan como los mensajes emitido por el usuario que esta conectado, ose por mi. Y los mensajes que están en **Gris** sean los mensajes recibidos por el usuario.

[image: Esta es la apariencia de mi chat]

Los 3 mensajes que aparecen en la foto son en realidad 2 mensajes que tengo almacenados en mi base de datos emitidos los dos por mi usuario, pero le esta mostrado los mensajes a la persona que no debe. Si miran la base de datos, el campo **id_emisor** se esta almacenado el id del usuario que emitió el mensaje y en el campo **id_receptor** se esta mostrando el id del usuario que tiene que recibir el mensaje. En la foto de arriba en la url lo que le estoy pasando por **$_GET['user']** es el id del usuario que debe recibir el mensaje **id_receptor** en el campo de la base de datos

[image: Asi esta compuesta la tabla messege de mi base de datos]

**Este es el HTML donde muestro los mensajes:**

```
<div class="chat-sala">
            
            <!-- Este es el archivo donde esta la logica SQL para sacar los mensajes -->
            <?php require_once('messege/emisor.php') ?>

            <?php foreach($receptor as $receptor) : ?>

                <!-- Mensajes que me han enviado | Receptor -->
               <div class="col s12">
                    <img src="images/user.png" alt="Mi nombre" class="col s2 m2 xl1 img-adaptable circle" height="50">
                    <span class="black-text emisor left grey lighten-4" title="27 de marzo 2021">
                    <?=$receptor['messege']?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach ?>

            <?php foreach($emisor as $emisor) : ?>
                
                <!-- Mensajes que he enviado yo | Emisor -->
                <div class="col s12">
                    <img src="images/yo.jpg" alt="Mi nombre" class="col s2 m2 xl1 img-adaptable circle right" height="50">
                    <span class="white-text right pink receptor" title="27 de marzo 2021">
                        <?=$emisor['messege']?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            <?php endforeach ?>

            </div>
```

**Resultado esperado:**
Solo quiero que los mensajes que yo he enviado aparezcan en el div de color pink - Rosado y los mensajes recibidos aparezca de color grey. Pero no esta sucediendo me esta mostrando los mensajes que yo he enviado de color Gris y Rosado. Los 3 mensajes que muestra los he enviado yo y son un total de 2 mensajes. 1 de o las 2 consultas están fallado y mi logica no me alcanza para resolverlo.

Si desean un poco mas de información por favor solo háganmelo saber para actualizar el post, un cordial saludo.

Comment: A ver si entendi, Tu enviaste 2 mensajes, de los cuales 2 se muestran en gris uno de ellos en rosado, cuando los 2 deberian salir en rosado cierto? pero tambien mencionaste que el mensaje se le muestra a la persona incorrecta, a que te refieres? que el mensaje en gris deberia salir en rosado? o que le enviaste el mesnaje a alguien mas?

Comment: Ademas por lo que veo, basta con tener 1 sola consulta, a ver si me explico, al abrir el chat de la persona deberias obtener el id de ese usuario, en una sola consulta podrias comparar el id de ese usuario con el id de tu usuario para mostrar todos los mensajes, en una respuesta te dare mejor el codigo

Comment: Exacto, todos los mensajes deberían de mostrarse en Rosado porque los he enviado yo, pero aparte de eso hay un error porque uno debería de mostrarse a Carlos y otro a Juan y están apareciendo los dos mensajes en el chat de Carlos y en el chat de Juan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Importante:** Aprovechando que estás usando la librería PDO, es recomendable ejecutar [consultas preparadas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/pdo.prepare.php) correctamente para minimizar riesgo de errores y ataques SQL. En este caso, lo más fácil es usar marcas `?` y proporcionar un arreglo con los datos de remplazo.

Puedes leer toda la **conversación** con una sola consulta, solo debes aplicar el filtro adecuado:

```
* (receptor = $receptor AND emisor = $id) - Devuelve solo los mensajes que enviaste a ese usuario
* (receptor = $id AND emisor = $receptor) - Devuelve solo los mensajes que ese usuario te envió
```

La combinación de los dos filtros te va a dar la conversación completa, pero aún faltan cosas por resolver, por ejemplo:

**¿Es conveniente unir otras tablas para obtener datos de emisor y receptor?**
En cada registro se van a repetir esos campos.

```
<?php
$consulta = "SELECT messege.messege, messege.photo_messege, messege.create_at_messege, messege.id_emisor, messege.id_receptor,
        emisor.name as ename, emisor.surname as esurname, emisor.photo_profile as ephoto,
        receptor.name as rname, receptor.surname as rsurname, receptor.photo_profile as rphoto
    FROM messege
    LEFT JOIN users emisor ON users.id_user = messege.id_emisor
    LEFT JOIN users receptor ON users.id_user = messege.id_receptor
    WHERE (messege.id_emisor = ? AND messege.id_receptor = ?) OR (messege.id_emisor = ? AND messege.id_receptor = ?)";

// Ejecutar consulta:
$prep = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
// Ejecutar enviando parámetros
$prep->execute([$id, $receptor, $receptor, $id]);
$mensajes = $prep->fetchAll();
```

Puedes unir la misma tabla 2 o más veces, siempre que le asignes un alias distinto `LEFT JOIN tabla alias1 ... LEFT JOIN tabla alias2` y, por supuesto, también los campos deben tener su propio alias, para identificarlos fácilmente.

**Nota:** No incluyo aquí la opción para mostrar mensajes porque la lógica es más complicada de lo que realmente se necesita... continúa leyendo.

### Solución más viable

**¿No sería mejor obtener los datos de usuarios aparte?**
Yo creo que sí, porque:

- En teoría, ya deberías tener la información del usuario en sesión
- Solo debes hacer una consulta adicional para obtener los datos del otro usuario

La ventaja es que, aparte de simplificar la consulta de mensajes, también garantizas que el usuario existe.

```
<?php
// Definir variable ID para usuario en sesión
$id = $_SESSION['id_user'];
// Definir la variable receptor con asignación ternaria
$receptor = (isset($_GET['user'])) ? $_GET['user'] : 0;
// Obtener datos del otro participante en la conversación
$consUsuario = "SELECT name, surname, photo_profile FROM users WHERE id_user = ?";
$prepUser = $conexion->prepare($consUsuario);
$prepUser->execute([$receptor]);
// Esto ayuda para verificar que el usuario realmente existe
if($prepUser->rowCount() == 0) {
        // No se encontró el usuario, se debe mostrar error y terminar
        die('No existe el usuario seleccionado');
}
// Crear un arreglo con ambos usuarios, con su ID como índice:
$usuarios = [
    $_SESION['id_user'] => [
        'name' => $_SESSION['name'],
        'surname' => $_SESSION['surname'],
        'photo_profile' => $_SESSION['photo_profile'],
    ],
    $receptor => $prepUser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
];

$consulta = "SELECT messege, photo_messege, create_at_messege, id_emisor, id_receptor
    FROM messege
    WHERE (id_emisor = ? AND id_receptor = ?) OR (id_emisor = ? AND id_receptor = ?)";

// Ejecutar consulta:
$prep = $conexion->prepare($consulta);
// Ejecutar enviando parámetros
$prep->execute([$id, $receptor, $receptor, $id]);
$mensajes = $prep->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Ahora, para recorrer los mensajes y crear el HTML también será más sencillo:

```
            <div class="chat-sala">
            
<?php
// Incluye el archivo para obtener todos los mensajes
require 'messege/mensajes.php';
foreach($mensajes as $mensaje) :
    if($mensaje['id_emisor'] == $receptor) {
        // Este mensaje fue enviado por el otro usuario
        $clase = 'black-text emisor left grey lighten-4';
    } else {
        // Este mensaje fue enviado por el usuario en sesión
        $clase = 'white-text right pink receptor';
    }
    // Obtener datos del emisor
    $usuario = $usuarios[$mensaje['id_emisor']];
?>
                <!-- Mensajes que me han enviado | Receptor -->
               <div class="col s12">
                    <img src="<?php echo $usuario['photo_profile']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $usuario['name']; ?>" class="col s2 m2 xl1 img-adaptable circle" height="50">
                    <span class="<?php echo $clase; ?>" title="<?php echo $mensaje['create_at_messege']; ?>">
                    <?php echo $mensaje['messege']; ?>
                    </span>
                </div>
<?php
endforeach;
?>
            </div>
```

Esto simplifica la forma de generar el HTML y solo faltaría que apliques cambios necesarios como ruta de la foto de perfil y formato de fecha.

Comment: No me esta sacando ningún mensaje, el chat esta en blanco. sin errores pero no muestra nada

Comment: Ejecuta esta consulta en PhpMyAdmin `SELECT messege, photo_messege, create_at_messege, id_emisor, id_receptor FROM messege WHERE (id_emisor = 1 AND id_receptor = 2) OR (id_emisor = 2 AND id_receptor = 1)` así puedes ver si hay algún error.

Comment: Me esta sacando dos registro con mensajes

Comment: Yo creo que el error lo tengo yo debido a mi falta de experiencia en la programación, ya que lo que he hecho es copiar el código tal cual tu me los has dado y sospecho que mi problema radica en `?` ya que no lo estoy comparando con nada en la consulta SQL

Comment: Las marcas `?` son remplazadas con los valores al ejecutar la consulta con `$prep->execute([$id, $receptor, $receptor, $id]);`. entonces, haz una depuración básica: antes de ejecutar la consulta agrega: `var_dump($consulta, $id, $receptor);` para ver que los datos son correctos. **Nota:** Acabo de modificar la respuesta para definir las variables al inicio del script, asumí que ya lo habías hecho, pero probablemente faltaba ese paso.

Comment: He logrado solucionar la mayoría de los problemas, ya solo quedan 2 problemas

Comment: Me gustaría enviarte una captura de pantalla para que veas de forma visual mucho mejor lo que sucede

Comment: Sí, edita tu pregunta para agregar esa captura de pantalla, va a ser muy útil para tratar de ayudarte.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119941/discussion-between-braylin-ivan-payano-and-triby).

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero que veo:

Supongamos que tu id es 1 y el de tu compañero es 2
Entonces, al abrir el chat deberias obtener el id de tu compañero, tu id ya deberias tenerlo guardado en una variable $_SESSION, entonces suponiendo todo esto la consulta deberia quedarte de la siguiente forma

```
$_SESSION['usuario'] = 1;
$receptor = 2; // o de donde obtengas el id de tu compañero
$stetament = $conexion->prepare(
    "SELECT 
users.id_user, 
users.name, 
users.surname, 
users.photo_profile, 
messege.messege, 
messege.photo_messege, 
messege.create_at_messege,
id_emisor,
id_receptor 
FROM messege 
INNER JOIN users ON users.id_user = messege.id_receptor 
WHERE id_emisor = :emisor AND id_receptor = :receptor"
);
$stetament -> bindParam(':id_receptor',$receptor,PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stetament -> bindParam(':id_emisor',$_SESSION['usuario'],PDO::PARAM_STR);
$stetament -> execute();
```

Ya por aqui tienes la consulta, obtendras todos los mensajes que sean igual a tu id usuario con el id de tu compañero
Ahora lo siguiente, en mi conocimiento uso un while que me ira recorriendo cada consulta y me la ira mostrando de la siguiente forma

```
<div class="chat-sala">
            
            <!-- Este es el archivo donde esta la logica SQL para sacar los mensajes -->
            <?php require_once('messege/emisor.php') ?>

            <?php while($mensaje = $stetament -> fetch()){ 
             if($mensaje['8'] == $receptor){
             ?>

                <!-- Mensajes que me han enviado | Receptor -->
               <div class="col s12">
                    <img src="images/user.png" alt="Mi nombre" class="col s2 m2 xl1 img-adaptable circle" height="50">
                    <span class="black-text emisor left grey lighten-4" title="27 de marzo 2021">
                    <?php echo $mensaje['messege']?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            <?php }else
               if($mensaje['7'] == $_SESSION['usuario']){
           ?>      
                <!-- Mensajes que he enviado yo | Emisor -->
                <div class="col s12">
                    <img src="images/yo.jpg" alt="Mi nombre" class="col s2 m2 xl1 img-adaptable circle right" height="50">
                    <span class="white-text right pink receptor" title="27 de marzo 2021">
                        <?php echo $mensaje['messege']?>
                    </span>
                </div>
            <?php }} ?>
            </div>
```

Cuentame como te fue

//Actualizacion //

Uno de los errores que veo en tu consulta es que estas buscando en el campo id_user de la tabla messege

```
$stetament = $conexion->prepare(
    "SELECT users.id_user, users.name, users.surname, users.photo_profile, messege.messege, messege.photo_messege, messege.create_at_messege FROM messege INNER JOIN users ON users.id_user = messege.id_receptor WHERE users.id_user = $receptor"
);
```

Por lo que entiendo estas tratando de comparar en la tabla users que `id_user` es igual a `$receptor`, cosa que esta mal, como estas buscando en `messege` deberias de comparar que `id_receptor = $receptor`

Comment: Me esta lanzando este error: **Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\geyland\messege\emisor.php on line 22**

Comment: la linea 22 cual es?

Comment: `$stetament -> execute();`